# Best way to display span element on next line in mobile view

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for the best solution to display these span elements here:
[image]

I tried the following:

```
.card {
      .gallery-text {
        display: flex;
        // margin-left: 60px;
        // display: block;
      }
```

`display: flex;` is actually what is causing the link to rub up against the word View and to, but `display: flex;` is what helps the span element show up on the next line.

Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: try `flex-direction: column`. Please show your HTML also

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, your suggestion gives it a vertical alignment.

Comment: Please show you HTML, I guess I knw how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution : Just use a `<br>` Tag.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags are called block level elements, and will skip lines automatically.

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>other stuff</p>
```

`<span>` tags are inline elements, and will not break lines (skip line) unless they are told to with a `<br/>` tag.

```
<span>some text</span>
</br>
<span>other stuff </span>
```

alternatively, in the example provided, you can use `&nbsp;` to force a “non breaking space” character in between the link an text.

```
<span>...full gallery</a>&nbsp;to</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting a `display: flex;` with `flex-direction:row` and `justify-content:center;` for the `.gallery-text`, in mixin, but then I had to go to `.view-full-gallery` and add a `padding-left: 5px;` and `padding-right: 5px;` and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Set a media query and add

```
span{
white-space: pre;
}
```